# How can I search for a div attribute that is indented to another div attribute using bs4?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a python script that scrapes the UEFA webisite for Live Scores but I can't find the attribute containing the match scores because it is in another div attribute.

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import date
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

today= date.today()
d= today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

page = requests.get("https://www.uefa.com/livescores/?date=" + d) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

matches_list = soup.find_all("div", class_="matches-list")

print(matches_list)
```

I'm wondering if I can search for that attribute right from the top without going down the three.

Comment: Does that div have an id or any other identifying features?

Comment: no, just the class name

Comment: The match scores are loaded via ajax. You can't find them in the site HTML.

Comment: If they are loaded in via ajax then you would need to either use a request library that supports javascript execution e.g. requests-html or use browser automation like selenium first.

Answer (score 2):

This sites uses an API call on :

```
GET https://match.uefa.com/v2/matches
```

with some query parameters for the date, pagination and competitionIds

It requires an api key that is embedded in a javascript tag. One solution is to use regex to extract this api key and then use `requests` to make the call:

```py
from datetime import date
import requests
import re

today = date.today()
d = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

r = requests.get("https://www.uefa.com/livescores/?date=" + d)
reg = re.search("apiKey.*['\"](.*)['\"]", r.text, re.MULTILINE)
apiKey = reg.group(1)

r = requests.get("https://match.uefa.com/v2/matches",
                 params={
                     "fromDate": today,
                     "toDate": today,
                     "order": "ASC",
                     "offset": 0,
                     "limit": 100,
                     "competitionId": "18,39,14,27,38,22,19,2014,2017,5,28,9,1,13,3,2018,101,17,2008,23"
                 },
                 headers={
                     "x-api-key": apiKey
                 })
result = r.json()
data = [{
    "awayTeam": t["awayTeam"]["internationalName"],
    "homeTeam": t["homeTeam"]["internationalName"],
    "datetime": t["kickOffTime"]["dateTime"],
    "score": t["score"]["total"] if t.get("score") else {},
    "winner": {
        "reason": t["winner"]["match"]["reason"],
        "team": t["winner"]["match"]["team"]["internationalName"] if t["winner"]["match"].get("team") else ""
    } if t.get("winner") else {}
}
    for t in result
]
print(data)
```

which will print the match info with the scores if available at this time

```py
[{
    'awayTeam': 'Turkey',
    'homeTeam': 'Switzerland',
    'datetime': '2021-06-20T16:00:00Z',
    'score': {},
    'winner': {}
}, {
    'awayTeam': 'Wales',
    'homeTeam': 'Italy',
    'datetime': '2021-06-20T16:00:00Z',
    'score': {},
    'winner': {}
}]
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/UefaMatch)

### Edit

It seems you don't even need the api key which is much more simple:

```py
from datetime import date
import requests

today = date.today()
d = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

r = requests.get("https://match.uefa.com/v2/matches",
                 params={
                     "fromDate": today,
                     "toDate": today,
                     "order": "ASC",
                     "offset": 0,
                     "limit": 100,
                     "competitionId": "18,39,14,27,38,22,19,2014,2017,5,28,9,1,13,3,2018,101,17,2008,23"
                 })
result = r.json()
data = [{
    "awayTeam": t["awayTeam"]["internationalName"],
    "homeTeam": t["homeTeam"]["internationalName"],
    "datetime": t["kickOffTime"]["dateTime"],
    "score": t["score"]["total"] if t.get("score") else {},
    "winner": {
        "reason": t["winner"]["match"]["reason"],
        "team": t["winner"]["match"]["team"]["internationalName"] if t["winner"]["match"].get("team") else ""
    } if t.get("winner") else {}
}
    for t in result
]
print(data)
```